# Swift array of protocol typed object

Tags: inheritance, swift, dynamic-linking

I have next inheritance:

```
protocol P {
    var a : Int { get set }
}

class C : P {
    var a : Int
    ...
}
```

And then i want to create generalised array and iterate through it with some action:

```
class Main {
    var array : Array<Proto>
    var inst : Proto
    ...
    func foo() {
        array.append(C(a:10))
        for obj in array {
            obj.a = 20      //Error: Cannot assign to the result of this expression
        }

        inst = C(a:10)
        inst.a = 20         //Works correctly

        for var i = 0; i < arr.count; ++i {
            inst = arr[i]
            inst.a = 20     //No problem even here
        }
    }
}
```

If i cast: (obj as C).a = 20 - then everything is OK. 
Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the for-in loop does not allow modification of the iterated item. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_154):

> NOTE
>
> The index constant exists only within the scope of the loop. If you want to check the value of index after the loop completes, or if you want to work with its value as a variable rather than a constant, you must declare it yourself before its use in the loop.

You can try the following:

```
    for obj in array {
        var c = obj
        c.a = 20      // This should work as c is a mutable copy of obj
    }
```

**Supplemental:**

Note what @ikuramedia said is correct. The above code masks the case where `obj` is a value type in which case `c` will be a copy of it and value `obj` in the array **will not** actually be modified.

Comment: This is not a good answer. It would be better to ensure we have a class type there. This one won't even crash.

Answer (score 1):

Protocols can be applied to Classes, Structs and Enums equally, so in your code the compiler cannot assume that obj is an object type. Because of this, it doesn't know whether obj is a reference type or a value type. If it were a value type then you couldn't alter the object without a mutating method, and therefore it assumes your code is not type correct and fails to compile.

You could either declare array to be of type AnyObject conforming to Proto, or you could downcast in the for loop iterator: `for obj as! C in array`

Comment: or the protocol as `@class_protocol`.

Comment: @ikuramedia: How would you go about `declar[ing] array to be of type AnyObject conforming to Proto`?

Comment: @Senseful - Actually you're right, I don't think you can declare it directly.  You either can declare the Protocol to be a class protocol, and then the Array is of types conforming to the protocol.  Or you can declare a reference type that conforms to the protocol and declare an array of that type (but then your array members have to be instances of that type).  Most likely I'd choose to downcast within the loop and let the type checker do the work of ensuring I'm getting reference types in my array, and then conditionally check whether they conform to the protocol before using them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been already described by others - to summarize:

1. the iterator is always constant
2. the protocol can be adapted by both classes and structs

If the protocol were adapted by a struct, the assignment would fail because we cannot assign properties of constant structs (and the iterator `obj` is constant).

There are two approaches to fix this:

1. Declare the protocol as a class protocol so that it cannot be adapted by structs:

   ```
   protocol P : class {
       var a : Int { get set }
   }
   ```

   This will ensure any objects conforming to `P` must be reference types.
2. Modify the iteration to work for both structs and classes

   ```
   for i in indices(array) {
       array[i].a = 20
   }
   ```

   Now we can modify properties regardless of whether the elements are value or reference types. Note however, such iteration is only valid if you are modifying the contents of elements in-place.  Insertions and removals will invalidate the indices returned by `indices(array)`.

   Further, you must take care to ensure that you are modifying the content in-place.  Concretely, code like this will have not actually modify the contents of array when the elements are value types:

   ```
   for i in indices(array) {
       var element = array[i]
       element.a = 20
   }
   ```